# Detect notdef with ECMAScript

Tags: photoshop, unicode-string, photoshop-script, ecma, mojibake

As far as I am aware, Photoshop is limited to using ECMA3. With this is in mind, is it possible to detect notdef characters in a text layer? - previously thought to be be mojibake, until JosefZ corrected me.

```
var theLayer = activeDocument.activeLayer;
if (theLayer.kind == "LayerKind.TEXT")
{
  // theLayer.textItem.font = "ArialMT"; // fails
  theLayer.textItem.font = "Meiryo"; // fine
  theLayer.textItem.contents = "グウェンステファニー";
}
```

`Result with Meiryo: グウェンステファニー`

`Result with Arial:  ���������`

*I'm using � character for illustration purposes only here :)

Comment: It's not [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), it's [Glyph 0 (the `.notdef` glyph)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/recom#glyph-0-the-notdef-glyph). The `.notdef` glyph is very important for providing the user feedback that **a glyph is not found in the font**.

Comment: Thanks @josefZ You're absolutely right!, I'll modify my question and title accordingly.